# Python: What does a dot before an integer mean?

Tags: python

I was reading some Python code:

```py
math.ceil(.1) + math.floor(.1)
```

and have encountered the following notation - `.1`.

Could someone explain what does it mean?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a float. `.1` represent the decimal value `0.1`

```
>>> type(.1)
<class 'float'>
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 4):

The integer is a float (decimal) value

```py
>>> .1
0.1
>>> 1
1
```

As [**Shashank V**'s answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60043091/4541045), one can can check the type of an object by calling `type()` on it!

```py
>>> type(.1)
<class 'float'>
>>> a = .1
>>> type(a)
<class 'float'>
```

Answer (score 3):

.1 is a float, it's equivalent to 0.1